# React-Hooks: How to create reusable data table component with dynamic content

Tags: reactjs, datatable, react-hooks

In my application, I have the following data table which I want to make reusable. I tried to make a component based on the following code, however, the thead & tbody content has several types and varieties.

How can I make this reusable component?

```
<table className="table table-hover">
               <thead>
                   <tr>
                       <th>#</th>
                       <th> Title</th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                   {posts &&
                       posts.map(item => (
                           <tr key={item.id}>
                               <td>{item.id}</td>
                               <td>{item.title}</td>
                           </tr>
                       ))}
               </tbody>
           </table>
```

Comment: is your content(Which i assume posts array) having always id and title(at least)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the basic functional component.

```
const CustomTable = (posts) => {
    return (
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {posts &&
                    posts.map(item => (
                        <tr key={item.id}>
                            <td>{item.id}</td>
                            <td>{item.title}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
```

You can pass `posts` array wherever you need it.

```
<div className='table'>
    <CustomTable posts={posts} />
</div>
```

Comment: Also, table <thead> part, I want to reuseable.